Checkbox returns true when unchecked in Google Tag Manager
When testing in tag assistant the below variable returns true whether it's checked or unchecked.
`function checked() {
    var check = jQuery('#marketing').attr("checked");
    if(check === "checked") {
   return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}`

Tried return true.toString(); and return false.toString(); and it's still returning true either way. Any advice would be appreciated.
<input type="checkbox" name="marketing" id="marketing" style="padding:0;margin:0;" value="1" checked="checked" aria-require="true">

Above is the code for the checkbox.

You're misusing the .attr('checked'). See this as an example: How do I check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?
Besides, try not to use jquery or any other third party dependency whenever writing code in a TMS. That leads to problems later on. Use pure JS instead.

Thanks for your prompt response. I will have a look at how to run the function in JS and see if that works.
